# iOS AVFoundation not recognizing QR codes that have a color gradient

Tags: ios, xcode, qr-code

Running on iPhone 13 Pro with iOS 15.0.1 on the latest Xcode 13, my qr scanning app scans black and white QR codes without issue.

However, the app cannot scan color QR codes or gradient color QR codes.

I believe I have set up AVFoundation up correctly, or maybe not?

[Sample QR code with color gradient](https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjwh5qLBhALEiwAioods6hdvvQSRyg0-5f8ecaBOuCzhD1D5C2ROYWnRUoFdAbOVt1l8PYMjhoCJaUQAvD_BwE)

Not sure if my target iOS affects AVFoundation scanning abilities?